# How to improve config files for multiple clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, vue.js

I have an app in angularjs that uses nodejs and I am looking for some ideas to improve the configuration for the appConfig files
In these files I have some fields like

```
feature1 = false;
feature2 = false
```

I am using these values to show/hide some buttons/panels on different pages but I have 1 config file for each client I would like to reduce the number of config files or to improve this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's an angular specific question but in my Nuxt projects a have a script that generate a config file before app launch.
That script will generate a config file which contain a base config and some project specific options.
Maybe this approach will be helpful for you.

config/base.js

```js
module.exports = {
    api: '/api-path',
    someFeature: true,
    anotherFeature: true
};
```

config/production.js

```js
module.exports = {
    someFeature: false
};
```

config/clientOne.js

```js
module.exports = {
    anotherFeature: false
};
```

tools/config.js

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const base          = require('../config/base');
const production    = require('../config/production');
const dev           = require('../config/dev');
const clientOne     = require('../config/clientOne');
const clientTwo     = require('../config/clientTwo');

let result = Object.assign({}, base);

let map = {
    production,
    dev,
    clientOne,
    clientTwo
};

result = Object.assign({}, result, map[ process.env.NODE_ENV ]);

fs.writeFileSync('./static/config.json', JSON.stringify(result));
```

package.json

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "start:production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./tools/config.js && nuxt start",
        "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev node ./tools/config.js && nuxt",
        "start:clientOne": "cross-env NODE_ENV=clientOne node ./tools/config.js && nuxt",
        "start:clientTwo": "cross-env NODE_ENV=clientTwo node ./tools/config.js && nuxt"
    }
}
```